# How to set a post that a gate latches to, really close to the house siding?

Tags: fence, siding

I want to set a fence post that a door will be latching into. This post is currently attached to the siding through a couple of 2x4, and it just became detached of the siding. So, I am trying to find for a better solution.

As you can see I don't have a lot of space between the house and the door, so I am not sure what is the best way to do this. Should I dig a hole and bury the post with concrete in it? Should I put concrete and a U-bracket and have the post above the ground?

Updates:

- I live in Seattle, WA. Not a lot of extreme temperatures (a couple of snow days in winter, and a couple of heat waves in summer), but constant rain.
- I attached the picture of how the post (on left) is currently set up. Attached to the siding with screws via a couple of 2x4, but really wobbly (hence why I am trying to change this).

[image]

Comment: attach the post to the wall framing.

Comment: How deep was the hole when you hit the foundation (actually, may have been the footer)?

Comment: I've updated the question with some new findings!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pour a new small piece of concrete connected to the old add a U post bracket to the concrete and bolt the post to the bracket.

You can drill a hole in the footing and epoxy a piece of rebar to tie your new concrete to your footing (if that is what you hit).  I wouldn't remove a piece of the footing.

There are other options but without a picture it is hard to give recommendations.

Comment: Updated to provide more information. I have a question, why would I need to add a new small piece of concrete? Couldn't I add the U post bracket to the footing itself?

Comment: You could but then your metal connector and the bottom of the post are underground and will rust / rot out.  Also if you are bolting the post to the bracket then if the bolt connection ever needs tightening you can easily do that.  If the post needs replacement it is easy access.

Comment: You can see my post anchor in this answer. 
 https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/203321/how-to-replace-loose-4x4-wood-fence-post-with-a-steel-post/203322#203322

Comment: Oh, I get it now! You suggest bringing the concrete all the way to the floor level. That makes sense! Thanks, I think I'm going to do that.

Comment: Fresh Codemonger, hello again, my friend! So, it turned out that what I hit on the ground was not footing/foundation, just an old piece of concrete. So, having said this, would you still suggest having the post connected to concrete above ground, VS putting concrete and post in the hole? Since this is the post that the door will be closing against (where the latch will be), I'm concerned of the stability of it if I do the U post bracket, VS burying it in a hole with concrete.

Comment: Another concern I have is that I don't have a lot of space to set the "foundation" for the post, since the gate and the house are so close to it. I don't know how much of diameter I am going to need, but the post space is just 4 inches from the house.

Comment: In your case since you don't have a sidewalk,  I'd probably just get a long post and put 1/3 of it in the ground.  Add concrete around the post, you won't have a lot between the post and the foundation wall but that shouldn't matter too much.  How far were you thinking of putting the post down?  4" on all sides should be fine for the post.

Comment: From the wall to the gate, I have exactly 8 inches. I was planning on putting a 1/3 of the post down.

Answer (score 0):

Generally it can be ok to drill through that concrete. However My assertation is based on my location (fla.)  More information would be helpful. Where are you located on this planet?  What type of structure is the foundation supporting? Is there a ground freeze issue?  High ground water?  What type of soil?
Attaching to the exterior wall could be the only solution, but that comes with the risk of allowing water infiltration at the attachment points and future problems. Give us more info please.

Comment: Added some information to address some of the questions that I have answers to :)

Comment: So are you repairing or adding a wood fence?  If so start with a small section of fence. Say 10-14 inches to move the main post away from the house and foundation.  Then you can dig your post hole deeper without hitting the concrete. The small section can be attached to a 2x4 close to the house that does not have to be buried very deep as it is small and has far less weight and is supported on the opposite side by the new post.

Comment: I am just trying to repair the post that is closest to the house (shown in the picture). That post is the one that the gate of the fence is closing to. 

The reason I am trying to repair is because right now the 2x4 have become loose from the siding (the screws have given up from all the back and forth of the gate). 

I could move that post further, but then I would have to also move the door further, which is not ideal. Thanks for the idea, I will consider it!

Comment: Ok now we have a more complete idea of what you are trying to accomplish.  As was asked earlier, how deep did you dig before hitting the cement?

Comment: RMDman, I will measure and come back to you!

Comment: turns out what I hit was not footing/foundation, it was just an old piece of concrete, that I could remove (not big diameter). So, I see three options:


1. Screwing it in the siding (this is what it was, and the post just got woobly and detached from the siding).
2. Make a hole and put the post in with concrete.
3. Put concrete and a U bracket at the floor level and then put the post in it.

Any preferences based on the fact that this post is the one that the door will be latching to?

Comment: Place the post as deep as possible and compress the soil around it without cement.  Cementing around wood posts will hold moisture around the wood and cause it to rot quicker.

Comment: RMDman, thanks for your comment! Wouldn't that wooble, specifically if this post will be the one that the gate latches to? What do you think of adding cement all the way to the top, and then putting the post with a bracket on the cement as @fresh codemonger suggested in his answer?

Comment: The method that @fresh codemonger suggested will work. My method will as well. If you were to carefully compact the dirt around the post it will be as strong as cementing without the risk of water being trapped next to the post.  It's really your choice.